# Arquivo existe mas não faz o include (require_once)

Tags: php, include

Tenho uma hospedagem (de qualidade duvidosa), estou fazendo um `require_once` onde verifico se o arquivo existe, e está dando erro:

> Warning: require_once(/home//base/Core\Application.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home//base/config/autoload.php on line 106
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home//base/Core\Application.class.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.5/pear') in /home//base/config/autoload.php on line 106

Meu Autoload:

```
function cleanPath($lib, $file, $ds = '/') {
    $lib = rtrim($lib, '/\\');

    $path = strtolower($lib.$ds.$file);
    $path = str_replace(['\\', '/'], $ds, $path);

    return $path;
}

spl_autoload_register(
    function ($class){
         global $autoloadlog;

         $libs = [BASE, APPS.APP.DS];
         $ext  = '.class.php';
         $debug = !TRUE;

         $file = FALSE;

         $autoloadlog .= '<h3>'.$class.'</h3>';

         foreach ($libs as $lib) {
            $path = cleanPath($lib, $class.$ext, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

             $autoloadlog .= '<pre>Lib: ' . (is_array($lib) ? implode(', ', $lib) : $lib) . PHP_EOL . 
                            'File: ' . $class.$ext . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . 
                            'Path: ' . $path . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . 
                            (file_exists($lib.$class.$ext) ? 'EXISTS!' : 'NOT exists!') . PHP_EOL . 
                            'BackTrace: ' . var_export(debug_backtrace(), true) . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . 
                            str_repeat('-', 200) . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL.'</pre>';


             if (file_exists($path)){
                  $file = $lib.$class.$ext;
                  break;
             }
         }

         //$file = search_lib($libs, $class.$ext);

         // Debug
         if ($debug) echo $autoloadlog;

         // Se encontrou inclui o arquivo
         if ($file !== FALSE  && is_string($file) && $file !== '') {
             
             require_once $file;

             if (!class_exists($class, FALSE)){
                  trigger_error('Autoload error: File loaded, but class not found.' , E_USER_ERROR);
                  //throw new \Core\Exception\SystemException(\Core\Exception\Exceptions::E_CLASSNOTEXIST, [$class]);
             }

         } else { // Se não encontrar o arquivo lança um erro na tela. :)

             if (is_array($libs)) $libs = implode($class.$ext . '</code>, <code>', $libs);

             trigger_error("Autoload error: Can't find the file {$class}{$ext} on [{$libs}]!" , E_USER_ERROR);
             //throw new \Core\Exception\SystemException(\Core\Exception\Exceptions::E_FILENOTFOUND, ["<code>{$libs}".$class.$ext."</code>"]);
         }

    }
);
```

<sub>Obs.: Os arquivos são todos salvos com nomes em minúsculo (incluindo pastas), por isso faço um `strtolower` na função `cleanPath`.</sub>

Retorno:

```
<h3>Core\Application</h3><pre>Lib: /home/u456897378/base/
File: Core\Application.class.php

Path: /home/<user>/base/core/application.class.php

NOT exists!
BackTrace: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'function' => '{closure}',
    'args' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Core\\Application',
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'file' => '/home/<user>/public_html/index.php',
    'line' => 8,
    'function' => 'spl_autoload_call',
    'args' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Core\\Application',
    ),
  ),
)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

</pre><br />
<b>Warning</b>:  require_once(/home/<user>/base/Core\Application.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/home/<user>/base/config/autoload.php</b> on line <b>106</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/<user>/base/Core\Application.class.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.5/pear') in <b>/home/<user>/base/config/autoload.php</b> on line <b>106</b><br />
```

---

Resumindo, o arquivo existe, mas dá erro na hora de fazer o *include*, o que pode estar acontecendo?

Obs.: Funciona corretamente em ambiente local (XAMPP + Windows).

Comment: Notei umas barras estranhas no erro: `//base/Core\Application` é linux a hospedagem?

Comment: Precisa ver se não está misturando maiúsculas e minúsculas indevidamente. De acordo com o output, tanto as barras, como o @rray mencionou, quanto o _case_ estão misturados, notar aqui: `File: Core\Application.class.php` e `Path: /home/u456897378/base/core/application.class.php`. Pode até ser que o PHP seja amistoso com barras assim: `/` mas o case não tem jeito de funcionar bem misturando.

Comment: Talvez postar a função `cleanPath` ajude a achar o problema.

Comment: Sim @rray a hospedagem é linux, note que monto uma _string_ pra debugar e tem uma linha `Path: /home/<user>/base/core/application.class.php` esse é a _string_ que uso pra fazer o `include`.

Comment: @Bacco adicionei a função, basicamente só passo a _string_ pra _lowercase_ e altero as barras para `/`.

Comment: não entendi porque tem  `/home/<user>/base` e depois tem  `/home/u456897378/base` e no erro diz `/home//base`. Afinal, qual o caminho certo do arquivo e como está invocando a classe para chamar o autoload?

Comment: Já descobri o problema, obrigado a todos... Foi apenas falta de atenção.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu sei que você já resolveu o problema, mas só queria apontar o possivel problema, aqui você usa:

```
$path = cleanPath($lib, $class.$ext, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

Pra pegar o `$path`, já aqui você tenta refazer o `$path` sem limpar ele:

```
 $file = $lib.$class.$ext;
 break;
```

E por isto na sua resposta funcionou, isto provavelmente foi devido a você estar usando linux, aonde os arquivos são sensiveis quando usa-se letras maiusculas e minusculas, por isto ao usar `cleanPath` funcionou, pois dentro dela você usar `strtolower`.

Comment: Exatamente isso Guilherme, não sei o motivo do Linux ser assim, mas no Windows pode-se usar `UpperCase/com\barras` que funciona corretamente.. ¬¬

Comment: @KaduAmaral o linux se baseia em muitas coisas no unix (apesar de ambos não terem ligação alguma), o DOS que quis inventar maneiras novas rs. O Windows só herdou os problemas :p

Answer (score 1):

Utilizei uma *string* para verificar se o arquivo existe, mas utilizei outra para fazer o *require*:

```
if (file_exists($path)){
   $file = $lib.$class.$ext;
   break;
}
```

Solução:

```
if (file_exists($path)){
   $file = $path;
   break;
}
```